# How to display another window after successful Login from the login window?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have two classes like below:

```
class Login(QMainWindow):
    ...
    ...

class WinOne(QMainWindow):
    ...
    ...
```

`Login` class has the Login window.

`WinOne` class has the post-login window.

I am importing these two classes into another module and I want to display the window from the `WinOne` class after successful login from the login window of the Login class.

I am not sure how to close the first window and open another window.

I am not able to apply this logic.

If someone can suggest just the logic, I'll try to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a blocking way to show the login dialog and access the results. It can be done by using `exec()` and seeing the results when it returns :

```
login = Login()
winOne = WinOne()

if login.exec():
    result = login.successfulLogin;
    if result:
       winOne.show()
    else:
       ...
```

Another option is to use the asynchronous way. You can have a signal in `Login` to show the login is successful and connect it to `show()` slot of `WinOne` :

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(login, QtCore.SIGNAL('LoggedIn()'), winOne, QtCore.SLOT('show()'))
```

Comment: I missed to mention its Python 2.7...so I don't have exec() here. Please suggest

Comment: @PEJK You can also use the asynchronous way. I have updated the answer.